# Trying to understand why the parent process in this code gets the correct value piped from the child process

Tags: c, pipe, fork

The code is shown below. I am trying to understand why does the parent not continue executing while the child is waiting for the user input. I was expecting the parent process to read some gibberish and print it since the child and parent would run independently. But the parent waits for the child to get the input scanned before it prints it correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int pipe_fd[2];
    if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        close(pipe_fd[0]); // Close the reading end in the child
        
        int numberToSend;
        printf("Enter a number to send to parent: ");
        scanf("%d", &numberToSend);
        
        write(pipe_fd[1], &numberToSend, sizeof(numberToSend));
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // Parent process
        close(pipe_fd[1]); // Close the writing end in the parent
        int receivedNumber;
        read(pipe_fd[0], &receivedNumber, sizeof(receivedNumber));
        close(pipe_fd[0]);

        printf("Parent received number: %d\n", receivedNumber);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you read from a pipe, you wait for something to be written to the pipe.

Comment: Why would you expect to read gibberish, what would be the point of that? How is the reading process supposed to tell the difference between gibberish and what was actually written to the pipe?

Comment: If you execute a command line `some_program | cat` do you expect `cat` to print gibberish until `some_program` produces output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting the parent process to read some gibberish and print it since the child and parent would run independently.

But they don't run *completely* independently.  At minimum, they compete for execution resources.  But more importantly, pipes are an *inter-process* communication mechanism that follows the simple rule that whatever is written to the write end can be read from the read end.

But pipes don't create data *de novo*. The semantics of an ordinary (non-blocking) `read()` are that the caller blocks until data are available.  Not necessarily the full number of bytes requested, but at least one.  Thus, if the parent attempts to read from the pipe, and the child is the only process that may write to the pipe, then parent cannot proceed until the child writes.  This is quite intentional, and it is another way in which this particular parent and child are not completely independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

By default, with pipes `read()` is a [*blocking* operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)), meaning it stops and waits for data to become available from the file descriptor.

`fcntl` (`F_SETFL`) can be used with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to change the pipe to non-blocking.

For example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipe_fd[2];
    if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    int flags = fcntl(pipe_fd[0], F_GETFL);
    if (-1 == fcntl(pipe_fd[0], F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK)) {
        perror("fcntl");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        close(pipe_fd[0]);

        int numberToSend;

        printf("Enter a number to send to parent: ");

        if (1 == scanf("%d", &numberToSend))
            write(pipe_fd[1], &numberToSend, sizeof(numberToSend));

        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        close(pipe_fd[1]);

        int receivedNumber;
        ssize_t rc = read(pipe_fd[0], &receivedNumber, sizeof(receivedNumber));

        if (rc == sizeof receivedNumber)
            printf("Parent received number: %d\n", receivedNumber);
        else if (EAGAIN == errno)
            fprintf(stderr, "Parent did not wait for data!!\n");
        else
            perror("read");

        close(pipe_fd[0]);
    }

    int status;

    while (wait(&status) > 0);

    printf("Child(%ld) exited with status: %d\n",
            (long) child_pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
Parent did not wait for data!!
Enter a number to send to parent: 42
Child(67023) exited with status: 0
```